# strip_tags + htmlentities + special in textarea with WYSING editor

Tags: php, textarea

I have a trouble with a textarea input that have a WYSING editor (Simple), the DB/rows are in UTF8_general_ci, and now i set the html text in the template with this:

```
htmlentities(utf8_decode($row['field'])
```

The problem is the WYSING editor, if the user put a `<strong> <P>` or similar, the text show in the template is the string code of the tag, not the code, because i use htmlentities, but if i not use this, and show the raw text, the problem is "the special tags", for example `<script>, <iframe>`.

The solution for this is the use of strip_tags(), allowing ONLY the used for the editor.. but one problem persist to this.. if the user, use for example `<p onclick="alert('fckoff!')">HELLO!</p>`, the alert is show because its allowed HTML tag.

Exists, any method, to allow ONLY certain tags + prevent scape special chars (like ', ", ñ, or '`´) + limit this "secutiry issures"?

Tanks!

Comment: You have to clean just xss vulnerabilities, are you using any PHP framework, as creating xss clean function is not easy?

Comment: No, its a handmade CMS, and no have xss clean function created yet. any recomended?

Answer (score 0):

you could make a function to remove any content you don't want, using regular expressions.

For example to remove the onclick js event you could do something like:

```
$field = preg_replace('/onclick=\"[^"]*\"/', '', $field);
```

for multiple tags you coud:

```
$field = preg_replace('/(onclick|onload|onwhatever|...)=\"[^"]*\"/', '', $field);
```

Comment: ok, its a "manual-solution-problem", i work now in the handmade script to clean this bugs. Tanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using a custom CMS/Framework so its a very complicated thing, I suggest you to copy function(s) from a Framework like CodeIgniter, here you will find a good code (`public function xss_clean`) https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php

You can modify it according to your need. And keep your code updated with the above link's function to be secure from new threats.